# Как удалить только нужную строку с вывода консоли, а не все что написано в консоли

Tags: c#, консоль, clear

Console.Clear() очищает всю консоль, а можно выборочно что то удалять? Если да, то как?

Comment: Представьте, что у вас есть маркерная доска, на которой вы можете написать все, что вашей душе угодно, в любом месте. Как происходит процесс удаления там? Наверно возьмете "ластик", поставите его в нужную позицию, и начнете стирать нужный кусок данных. Вот консоль это примерно тоже самое, где вы имеете "холст" на который можете написать в любом месте все, что угодно, и чтоб это что-то стереть, вам надо поставить "курсор" на нужные координаты, и начать затирать это пустыми символами. Получить текущую позицию - `GetCursorPosition()`, задать - `SetCursorPosition(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очистить только определённую область просто так нельзя, однако можно перезаписать символы в определённой позиции (в том числе и на пробелы):

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Simple fake progressbar: ");
// Запоминаем позицию курсора:
var pos = Console.GetCursorPosition();
Console.WriteLine("[....]");

// Ждём пол секунды
Task.Delay(500).Wait();
// Восстанавливаем позицию
Console.SetCursorPosition(pos.Left, pos.Top);
// Перезаписываем начиная с позиции курсора
Console.WriteLine("[@...]");

Task.Delay(500).Wait();
Console.SetCursorPosition(pos.Left, pos.Top);
Console.WriteLine("[@@..]");

Task.Delay(500).Wait();
Console.SetCursorPosition(pos.Left, pos.Top);
Console.WriteLine("[@@@.]");

Task.Delay(500).Wait();
Console.SetCursorPosition(pos.Left, pos.Top);
Console.WriteLine("[@@@@]");
```

Comment: `Task.Delay(500).Wait();` а зачем этот изврат? Если нужно синхронное ожидание, то лучше `Thread.Sleep(500);` не?

Comment: @aepot Я пользовался делеями максимум пару раз в жизни, и эти пару раз были вместе с async... Вот и не знал про другие

Comment: Вот когда нужно `await`, тогда `Task.Delay`. Исправьте, если не сложно. Ещё я бы советовал тапл разобрать сразу `(int left, int top) = Console.GetCursorPosition();`